# Not able to install some gems after mountain lion upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I just updated my Macbook to Mountain Lion, but now I'm not able to install some gems, because of the below error about headers. I looked around and it seems to have to do with Ruby headers missing. It was suggested to install Xcode, so I installed the full Xcode from the app store and also the Xcode command line tools. But still no luck. Any suggestions?

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Be sure to install Xcode's Command-Line Tools.

This [hint](https://gist.github.com/3181128) helped me with this issue:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Comment: Major props!! Somehow 10.8 uninstalled my cmd line tools? wtf?

Comment: Wow! This worked perfectly for me. (I just changed the command to my GCC version, 4.5.0.) I'm using OS Mavericks, so the same issue is still pertinent in 10.9.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get things working by just installing "Command Line Tools 10.8 for Xcode - Late July 2012" (not XCode itself) from:

- https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

  (Follow the "View all downloads" link from the Mac Dev Center page)

FYI, I did not have XCode installed on Lion, just the "Command Line Tools". Not sure if the new XCode command line tools will play nice with the old XCode.

Comment: I was looking for the 10.8 command line tools download,but couldn't find them, so thanks for the link.