# mysql2 gem Can't build native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, mysql2

Our intern's computer is having problems installing the mysql2 gem.  We just upgraded his computer from OS X 10.6 to 10.8 (Mountain Lion).  I have tried installing mysql through homebrew and through the 64 bit DMG installer.  I also tried symlinking to the dev tools (as pointed out here: [Not able to install some gems after mountain lion upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682429/not-able-to-install-some-gems-after-mountain-lion-upgrade)).  We have Xcode (4.4) installed and the command line tools installed.  We tried a reboot after installing the command line tools.

This is his PATH declaration from `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Symlink:

```
Diego-Blantons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ lmrunner07$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
Password:
```

Try to install gem:

```
Diego-Blantons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ lmrunner07$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling client.c
In file included from /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:8,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:105: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_long’ is negative
/Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_voidp’ is negative
In file included from /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34,
                 from /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382,
                 from /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:8,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:67: error: size of array ‘st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t’ is negative
client.c: In function ‘rb_raise_mysql2_error’:
client.c:98: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
client.c: In function ‘rb_mysql_client_socket’:
client.c:590: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
make: *** [client.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I've removed the homebrew installed mysql as well as the launch agent.  Also `rm -rf` the gem directory (Users/lmrunner07/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11)

Comment: Can you verify that your XCode 4.4 version is the re-release for both Lion and Mountain Lion?

Comment: Sorry, what would you like me to check?

Comment: When Mountain Lion was released, they updated Xcode 4.4 in the app store to be a version that is compatible with both Lion and Mountain Lion. If you didn't reinstall Xcode, it's likely that you have the version that's only compatible with previous versions of OS X.

Comment: We installed Xcode after we installed mountain lion

Comment: I was running into the same issue. Ended up removing RVM (wiping out the ~/.rvm directory) and reinstalling RVM. Worked great after that.

Comment: @JoshPinter - Just tried that.  `rvm implode` then removed the `~/.rvm` directory.  Same thing.  Thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. Installing homebrew `ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)`
   (check out their website for useage [Link](https://brew.sh/))
2. Following these instructions http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion
3. Reinstalling mysql with homebrew `brew install mysql`. (I tried installing mysql by follow these instructions http://erictarn.com/post/28269453881/how-i-installed-mysql-rvm-ruby-and-rails-on-mountain but i ran into issues later so i would recommend reinstalling mysql with homebrew.)
4. Reinstalling rvm and rails and the gems for my project (which included mysql2)

Note: When I tried to build I had a library issue, `Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib`, which was fixed by running `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` (refer to [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv) if you get the same issue.)

Comment: The intern is out today, so I can't try this out.  If if works, I'll be back with points.  Thanks for the links

Comment: The link in step 2 did it.  Not sure which step there did it, but thanks!

Comment: no worries. thanks for the points. im glad it worked. it took soooo many hours to solve it myself. i thought i should share.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
gem install mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
```

Replace the `/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config` with the location of your mysql config.

Comment: I think the command is: `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config`? (extra `--`) Got the same result, though

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the install process is very segmented and it's difficult to isolate what your problem might be without looking at your steps overall.

Without knowing more about your install steps, here are a few notes I followed that got me to a stable Rails Mountain Lion development box (again, apologies that this isn't more specific).

1. Instructions for RVM, Ruby: [moncefbelyamani.com](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)

   **Note:** There were certainly steps here that I took via suggestions from `brew doctor` and `'rvm requirements'` I've NEVER taken in previous setups.

   **Notes like:**

   - Xcode 4.3+ only use ruby-1.9.3-p125+ (and telling me if I had compilation issues to downgrade to Xcode 4.1)
   - Using `brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42`
   - Using `brew tap homebrew/dupes`
   - And others...
2. Rails specific Instructions: [railsapps.github.com](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html)
3. For mysql (skipping to the mysql part of the install: [coolestguyplanettech.com](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion)

**Note: I did the optional step:** ... in order to use mysql commands without typing the full path to the commands you need to add the mysql directory to your shell path... **as I've found doing so can help during builds, etc (some scripts assume...)**

Here, I tried to simply create a new rails app with the default database being mysql (which brought down mysql2 via bundler). From there - I tried to do a test app with a quick scaffold - and mysql2 barfed.

From there I hit an error 'Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib' and as noted here: [stackoverflow awesomeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv) 
I added this line to my .profile: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**MY PATH included rails and ruby explicitly:** `/Users/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/bin:/Users/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/gabriel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/gabriel/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:`

Hopefully, these resources will provide some additional help.

Comment: The intern is out today, so I can't try this out.  If if works, I'll be back with points.  Thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to compile by running:
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/mysql5_64/bin gem install mysql2
Where mysql5_64 I downloaded the latest 64bit version of mysql and extracted there. Leaving my already installed mysql databases intact.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by `implode`-ing rvm and installing Homebrew's ruby. Then, the mysql2 gem installed just fine.

This isn't the first problem like this that I've run into with rvm. I don't think I'll be using it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this successfully work on OSX Yosemite:

```
sudo port install mysql56
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysql_config
```