# uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2, nameerror

I just meet one `uninitialized constant`error,I have no idea on it now.Please save my day.

I'm trying to use mongodb & mysql2 simultaneously.Mongodb was OK.Now I want to add mysql2 gem into my project.

After 
`gem install mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` and add mysql2 into `Gemfile`.

When I restart server,it gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:12:in `<class:Client>': uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:2:in `<module:Mysql2>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:10:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/Liber/ktv/trunk/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

how Can i fix this guy? thank you.

```
 <class:Client>': uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS (NameError)
```

---------------------------Solution----------------------------

Just

```
brew install mysql
```

> DO NOT use DMG file to install mysql

and then :

```
sudo gem install mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Everything is OK now.

Thanks @BenjaminTan

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this link, which outlines [nicely how to setup MySQL on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693360/mysql2-gem-cant-build-native-extensions). The main takeway is to rely on `brew install` rather than the dmg file, as the OP has mentioned.

Comment: of course....../usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

Comment: Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.---------------but it also is  uninitialized constant

Comment: is it possible that I use OSX10.8.1,but mysql is only for OSX10.6?

Comment: Just

    brew install mysql

> DO NOT use DMG file to install mysql

and then :


    sudo gem install mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config



Everything is OK now.

Thanks @BenjaminTan