# How do I install mysql2 gem under Ruby 1.9.3? Works under 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, bundler, homebrew, mysql2

I'm having trouble installing the mysql2 gem on my machine.

I have OS X 10.8 with the latest Xcode, and mySql installed via Homebrew. All rubies installed using the latest RVM.

I can install mysql2 fine under ruby 2.0.0-p195

```
[~]$ rvm use 2.0.0                                                              [ruby-1.9.3-p429]
Using /Users/aselder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
[~]$ gem in mysql2                                                              [ruby-2.0.0-p195]
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11
1 gem installed
```

Under Ruby 1.9.3 and 1.8.7, it can't find the mysql.h file

```
    [~]$ rvm use 1.9.3                                                              [ruby-1.9.3-p429]
    Using /Users/aselder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
    [~]$ gem in mysql2                                                              [ruby-1.9.3-p429]
    Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /Users/aselder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for mysql.h... no
    checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
    -----
    mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
    -----
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/aselder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/aselder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/aselder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I've also tried all varieties of the command line options to get the gem to find the mysql installation:

e.g.
       gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, and I have not been able to figure it out

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  I am on a brand new machine (10.8).  Ruby 2.0 works without an issue and 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 complains that mysql.h is missing.

Comment: What's you MySQL version? I got the same problem using 5.6.12. Uninstalling it and installing 5.6.10 solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer and it solved my issues:
[Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Quoting:

On Ubuntu/Debian and other distributions using aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

On Red Hat/CentOS and other distributions using yum:

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

On Mac OS X with Homebrew:

```
brew install mysql
```

I'm on debian and after running the above command, I ran:

```
gem install mysql2
```

and it worked np.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem installing the gem with the mysql server started!

```
brew install mysql

mysql.server start

bundle install
```

Under ruby-1.9.3-p125.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `mysql` using Homebrew and the `mysql2` gem using Bundler.

```
brew update
brew install mysql
```

Add the following to your `Gemfile`

```
gem "mysql2"
```

Run:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I have done this, and still get the same error that @aselder is seeing

Comment: Ok, try to follow this guy answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693360/mysql2-gem-cant-build-native-extensions hope this will solve your issue guys :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by downgrading mysql from 5.6 to 5.5 through homebrew.  Can't provide a more detailed explanation, but it fixed it.

Comment: I'm currenlty having the same issue and am using 5.5.31

Answer (score 0):

I had a very silly solution to this: I opened Xcode and accepted the license agreement. Update downloaded a new version and I couldn't compile anything until the new agreement was manually accepted.