# gem install ffi -v '1.1.5' osx 10.8

Tags: macos, rubygems

I been trying to install ffi on OSX 10.8 via

```
gem install ffi -v '1.1.5'
```

with the result

```
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
mkdir -p "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386; (if [ ! -f       "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386/Makefile ]; then echo "Configuring libffi for i386"; cd "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386 && env CC=" xcrun cc" CFLAGS="-arch i386 " LDFLAGS="-arch i386" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/configure --disable-static --with-pic=yes --disable-dependency-tracking --host=i386-apple-darwin > /dev/null; fi); env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 make -C "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386
Configuring libffi for i386
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
configure: error: in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c/libffi-i386':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** ["/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-   i386/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

I have tried to follow

[An error occured while installing ffi (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725577/an-error-occured-while-installing-ffi-1-1-2-and-bundler-cannot-continue)

and

[Not able to install some gems after mountain lion upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682429/not-able-to-install-some-gems-after-mountain-lion-upgrade)

without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

My ffi installation failed with a pretty similar error message:

```
mkdir -p "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386; (if [ ! -f "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386/Makefile ]; then echo "Configuring libffi for i386"; cd "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386 && env CC=" xcrun cc" CFLAGS="-arch i386 " LDFLAGS="-arch i386" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/configure --disable-static --with-pic=yes --disable-dependency-tracking --host=i386-apple-darwin > /dev/null; fi); env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 make -C "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-i386
Configuring libffi for i386
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
configure: error: in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c/libffi-i386':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I spotted xcrun cc in the command and trying to run it manually gave me Apple's message that I had not agreed to XCode command line tools' license agreement. After the sudo xcrun cc the installation succeeded.

```
$ xcrun cc
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
$ sudo xcrun cc
You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.
Hit the Enter key to view the license agreements at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf'
...
```

```

Comment: This happens not only after a first installation of XCode, but anytime Apple changes the license. So an XCode update can cause the XCode tools to cease working until you have accepted the new license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ffi insists on building 32bit version while your system is running 64bit.

There most likely two ways to continue:

1. try to use latest version of the gem `gem install ffi` - but this does not have to work - as this needs to be fixed in the library,
2. compile 32bit ruby `rvm install 1.9.3-n32 --32` - but this also does not have to work as most libraries most likely will be compiled for 64bit, so it might not compile or compile and present issues

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `Xcode Command Line Tools` or https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer